# grant create database privilege to mariadb user

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, privileges

I know that in database management, it's a bad behavior to use the root user and I'm setting up a custom user with base privileges (create database, drop db, all access to all newly created dbs, etc).
I've created a user `antoine` which should be the base user used to login to the `mariadb server`.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to grant administration privileges like `create database xxx`, `drop database xxx`, etc... The documentation explains that to grant a privilege, you run the following command:

```
GRANT role ON database.table TO user@host
```

But, when it comes to server privileges, how can I do it ? I've tried the `*.*` instead of `database.table` but it's not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a user and then grant that user the privileges you want them to have like this.

```
CREATE USER 'antoine'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING 'a-password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON *.* TO 'antoine'@'localhost';
```

Comment: _ERROR 1372 (HY000): Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number_ - what is wrong with my password? using it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64484519/2147927) answer was fine

Answer (score 6):

Demo:

I create a user with privilege to connect but nothing else.

```
mysql> create user 'testy'@'%' identified by 'testy';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

I log in as that user and find they have no privilege to create a schema (synonym for database).

```
$ mysql -utesty -ptesty

mysql> create schema test2;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'testy'@'%' to database 'test2'
```

Log in as my admin user and grant them the privilege:

```
mysql> grant create on *.* to 'testy'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now my test user can do it:

```
$ mysql -utesty -ptesty

mysql> create schema test2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

I don't know what you mean by "it didn't work." That's not a good way to describe a problem. What was the command you executed? What happened when you did that command? Did it give an error? If so, what was the error?

Comment: My thought is that I might have forget to flush privileges and running the connected user on another terminal. So the grant table might not have been updated... But I learned, that there's no special commands for server privileges :D. Thanks noticing it to me.

Comment: In my example, I had to disconnect as testy and reconnect after the GRANT to get those privileges. But that's all. It's not necessary to FLUSH PRIVILEGES after GRANT/REVOKE.